# How to fix net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR in Ember REST Adapter

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm making an EmberJS application on port 4200 using Ember-Cli but it's using a database on port 8080. In my rest adapter, I overwrote find method (just to get something working) like this

```
find: function(store, type, id){
   return this.ajax('http://localhost:8080/api', 'GET');
}
```

which is the same as the original find method except that I replace the call to buildURL with a string representation of the host I want to call. Although on the server I explicitly allow cross origin requests, I'm getting a `net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` in the chrome browser. Furtherdown in the error message stack, there's reference to an EMBER.RSVP.Promise.hash.error... In my route, I use Ember.RSVP.hash like this

```
   model: function(){
       return Ember.RSVP.hash({
           store: this.store.find('mymodelname')
       });
   }
```

What can I do to make this GET request work?

Comment: If you just hit that endpoint in your browser does it work? It looks like a secure connection error, which is weird since you are hitting with http, have you tried https?

Comment: The hash in your model hook isn't necessary as well.